# Question about Generic Types in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

What am I doing wrong when declaring the function? I thought I was declaring generic types correctly but it keeps bugging out on vs code. Specifically the line where I'm exporting the function and using `<T>` and `</T>`

```
export interface OverviewCardProps<T> {
      actions?: ReactNode
      contentPerPage: number
      data: T[]
      heading?: ReactNode | string
      limit: number
      renderValue: ([]: T) => JSX.Element
      subheading?: ReactNode | string
    }
    
    export const OverviewCard = <T>({
      actions,
      data,
      contentPerPage,
      heading,
      limit,
      renderValue,
      subheading,
    }: OverviewCardProps</T>) => { }
```

Comment:  What is `</T>` supposed to be?  [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) aren't XML or HTML tags.  They don't get "closed"

Comment: well do you mind helping me out then on what I'm doing wrong lol, removing the closing tag still makes it messed up

Comment: I mean, maybe I would but this seems to depend on react and I don't use that.  If you don't need it, then you can untag "react" and change those types to `string` or something.  Presumably you should just change the "closing tag" to `<T>`, and possible change the, uh, "opening tag" to `<T,>` if it's confusing JSX (a trailing comma serves the purpose of distinguishing generics from JSX tags).  That gives me [this version](https://tsplay.dev/m3VjbN).  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, I'd need a [mre] I can use to investigate further.  Let me know.

Comment: Or use the `function` keyword instead of an arrow function expression https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcA5FATIwFDtIAekscwAHYwkUaunIB5AG6jpwJAHcAwiigkACnTABnADwAVAHy52cOOhjAIgnQH4AXPkvEyZuGhsjhG0RpQA5khOggCuIABGou4kKDAoTgYA2gC67gAWqCRCAY7ORKTkAD5wOjBQOe4ANqDAMCHhUVDuLIJkUABqKFWhwXAAFKmJAJRwALwmAFIAygAaAHQAolVIIEjC7jqhEZko2YK5TsguhXAlZRUH7BScPHzw1KGCGNaCcDJyCipqJIZG-Th3JZXjpMDE4igweZPMJ1jBfFB-EEoXBdvsAiiaiA6ijWu0uj0kCitjssjkwRQnB8oPIlKp1FoILo-qNAeYWDBQlA3nojHoAPRGa5AA which is usually what I do.